# How to get the exact photo taken with camera, when i try to send the photo to another activity

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I am building an app where i have to launch the camera, take a photo and send the photo to another activity for editing. But on the receiving activity the picture is blur and when i send the `URI` of the photo to the editor the photo becomes small.

how can i get the exact photo saved in gallery?

Here are the codes to launch camera and sending the photo to another activity:

```
 Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAM_REQUEST);

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(data != null) {
        if (requestCode == CAM_REQUEST) {
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(MainLayout.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("TakenPhoto", thumbnail);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }else{
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(MainLayout.this, MainLayout.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

the receiving activity:

```
thumbnail = (Bitmap)this.getIntent().getParcelableExtra("TakenPhoto");

    if(thumbnail != null){
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),thumbnail,"Title",null);
         myUri = Uri.parse(path);
        setImageURI(myUri,thumbnail);
    }

 private boolean setImageURI(final Uri uri, final Bitmap bitmap) {
    mImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    mImage.setBackgroundDrawable(null);

    mEditButton.setEnabled(true);
    mImageUri = uri;

    return true;
}
```